# What are Tasks and Frames in Real-Time?

Tags: task, real-time, rate

I am trying to understand the differences between tasks and frames in real-time system. If my understanding is correct, tasks are mainly the combination of different threads that need to be run at a specific rat. For example, I might have task `A` that has 10 threads. I need to run task `A` every   and I need to repeat the task every 30 ms (i.e. need to finish running all 10 threads by 30 ms). Also, If I cannot finish running everything with in by 30 ms, task 'A' will be "Overrunning".

In relation to this, what is a frame in real-time and how does it fit in with tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that "Passs" are often put out as "Frames" where each pass is actually the rate at which the scheduler runs each task.

e.g. If I have my system demading 100Hz rate:

```
TASKS    RATE(Hz)    FRAMES(PASS)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

TASK1   100         1

TASK2   50          2

TASK3   25          4

TASK4   12.5        8

TASK5   12.5        4
```

100 Hz can be divided as:

2 passes (each 50 Hz)

4 passes (each 25 Hz)

8 passes (each 12.5 Hz)

16 passes (each 6.25 Hz)

Silly things!